# What are the best ways to find errors in a sequence of messages (strings)?

Tags: algorithms

I am currently working on a thesis, where the main goal is to find errors (like a missing message, wrong sequence) in message sequences. The messages are distinguishable by their name, have further information in the message body, and are available in a database. Each message can just be thought of as string-representation of its name.

The thesis should compare different concepts for finding errors in these real-life message sequences. A big amount of these messages are being collected and the goal is to check for errors in the sequence or any missing messages. The default sequence (so the standard-case) can be defined.

Now I am just lacking any ideas on how to approach this problem. 
So, my questions are as follows: Which approaches can be used to solve this problem? Are there any algorithms, that could be used in this context?

Further example to make it clearer:

Message sequence A, B, C, D, E is defined for one standard-case.
Now, the real message sequence that is observed is A, B, C, E, D (or one message is missing entirely).

I hope the problem is comprehensible. Thanks to all who take the time to read.

Comment: I can only guess, but I suppose what you are looking for are [ECCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_code).

Comment: You might be interested in [the error detection of TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Error_detection)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question right, as you didn't specify whether this is a theoretical problem or a practical.

Assuming it is practical problem, there are quite some algorithms (e.g. [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)) depending on which layer your messages are being send (if they are being send at all).

Assuming it is more of a theorectial problem you can use stuff like the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).

Maybe check: *Computer Networks by Andrew S. Tanenbaum*

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It is both, a theoretical and practical problem. Lets say I have a big amount of messages already standardized in a database. I want to pick out different sequences, and check if these are like they should be. If there are any errors (e.g. order or missing) that is supposed to be found. 

I hope this makes more sense?